# Sending POST request with python to private OnionShare server in receive mode

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, tor, stem

Im trying to send data to a private onionshare server in receive mode with this simple program:

```
import socket
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9060'
s.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9060'

print(s.proxies)

url = 'http://*redacted*.onion'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

data = {
    'key':'*redacted*'
}

try:
    r = s.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, proxies=s.proxies)
    print(r.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I keep on getting this error:

```
SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='*redacted*.onion', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSConnection object at 0x7fdf710c5a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure'))
```

Tried the following:

- Tried changing the request to get. Got the same error message
- Tried connecting to a known onion address:

https://www.facebookwkhpilnemxj7asaniu7vnjjbiltxjqhye3mhbshg7kx5tfyd.onion/

This worked. Same thing with just curling it.

- Tried changing the port values in torrc, thats why the ports are 9060.
- Tried using the stem library to control the tor process. This gave me similar errors. Based on what ive read about stem I feel like its the way to go, but Unfortunately I havent had much luck with it yet.
- Tried making the onionshare public and sending a get request to it. This worked, so it seems like the problem has to do with the client authorization when the onionshare service is private.
- Tried adding ClientOnionAuthDir with a dir to the torrc file. I created a .auth_private file for the onionshare service with the onion address and private key with the format <onion addr without .onion>:x25519:< private key >. (I restarted tor as a service after changing the torrc file). After adding this to the torrc file i got the following from notices.log when trying to access the service both with the original program and through stem:

```
[notice] Fail to decrypt descriptor for requested onion address. It is likely requiring client authorization.
```

Note that im not sure what Content-Type the OnionShare server expects. Unfortunately I found very little on the matter when looking in their docs.

Comment: i get this error with the given code: `URL has an invalid label.`

Comment: which URL are you referring to? The one in the original code or the one i tried as a known onion address? I see now that the known onion address should not have a "." at the end of the url, and that when copying the address you get a space in the middle. I apologize for this and will edit it. Aswell as this i saw that to recreate the valid connection to the known onion address the tor service had to be started before you execute the python program. For me this was done by 'sudo service start tor'.

Comment: I think i found the major part of the issue. The OnionShare service is private so it requires authentication with a private key. I changed the service to public and tried it both with my program and a program using stem. This worked. So if anyone knows how the request should look to authenticate a user trying to access the private OnionShare service please share :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with client authorization. The issue was the format in my .auth_private file. I was missing 'descriptor' in between the onion address and the x25519. I also changed the program quite a bit, and started using stem. With these changes i managed to get the html from the onionshare page through a get request. After this i changed the code to make a post request with a message to the onionshare service. This worked.

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import requests

files = {'text':(None,'test')}

def request_over_tor(url):
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9061) as controller:
        # Provide your authentication here if needed
        # Signal Tor for a new circuit
        controller.authenticate(password='*redacted*')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        
        proxies = {
            'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9060',
            'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9060',
        }
       
        response = requests.post(url, proxies=proxies, files=files)
        return response.text

hidden_service_url = 'http://*redacted*.onion/upload'
response_content = request_over_tor(hidden_service_url)
print(response_content)
```